USB RNDIS Ethernet device should allocate fixed IP
I have a USB device (small RISC-V board) that works as a USB RNDIS Ethernet device. When I connect this device to my laptop, my laptop gets IP address from a specific range 10.42.0.0/24 - but always different. RISC-V board has static IP address (10.42.0.1)
I would like that my laptop would always get the same IP, because in that way I can set up internet sharing.
RISC-V board has Network Manager, however I can see only one connection:
cat /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Wired\ connection\ 1.nmconnection 

[connection]
id=Wired connection 1
uuid=618b7b33-0bf7-3691-bc9c-74a268e02953
type=ethernet
autoconnect-priority=-999
interface-name=end0

[ethernet]

[ipv4]
dns=8.8.8.8;8.8.4.4;
method=auto

[ipv6]
addr-gen-mode=default
method=auto

[proxy]

And ip a:
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: end0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether ca:df:35:bf:9c:bc brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enxcadf35bf9cbc
3: tunl0@NONE: <NOARP> mtu 1480 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ipip 0.0.0.0 brd 0.0.0.0
4: usb0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether e2:ae:04:31:fc:72 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.42.0.1/24 brd 10.42.0.255 scope global usb0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::e0ae:4ff:fe31:fc72/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

